# Pandas, separate by day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split a pandas dataframe to smaller ones based on the day. More specifically the dataframe consist of several observations in different days, days are numerate 1-31 for each month except those with 30 and 28 days. I am trying to iterate over the dataframe but it return empty dataframe, here is my code:

```
i=1
for i in range(len(df_sec)):
    df=prediction[prediction['day'] == i]
    i=i+1
print(df)
```

example of dataframe

| P | day |
| --- | --- |
| 1300 | 1 |
| 1400 | 1 |
| 1250 | 2 |
| 1300 | 29 |
| 1370 | 29 |
| 1300 | 30 |

Anyone knows why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: You're overwriting 'df' in every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-pandas-dataframe-by-column-value/) may prove useful.

For this one, `df_sec.groupby(df_sec['day'])` can get you a generator. Decompose it with a loop:

```
df_list = [i[1] for i in df_sec.groupby(df_sec['day'])]
# elements of the generator are tuples like (number, dataframe)
```

Plus, the auto-increment is unnecessary in the loop.